# radgridview wpf telerik current cell value is null

Tags: wpf, telerik, radgridview

I have a radgridview, the bug is when the user clicks on a cell without hitting the texblock, the datacontext is not passed. The currentcellinfo is always null. When the textblock is hit, it returns the value.

I've tried doing the code below and I am getting the values of all the cells in the row where i selected btu i couldn't determine the index of the cell I just selected. How can I get the cell value or at least column index within the row selected?

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="myGrid" SelectionMode="Extended">
    <telerik:RadGridView.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
    </telerik:RadGridView.LayoutTransform>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

I accessed it using the code: the code below works but since i get the first and break in a loop, it always gets the first cell/column. I do not know to say that the code should get the cell value accdg selectedindex

```
var item = myGrid.InputHitTest(point) as DependencyObject;

var test1 = EnumerateParents(item).OfType<Border>();

var test2 = test1.Select(c => c.DataContext).ToList();
var isbreak = false;

foreach (var t in test2) {
    foreach (var c in t.CastTo<IEnumerable>()) {
        if (c is tableCell) {
            rightClickItem = c.CastTo<tableCell)>();
            isbreak = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isbreak) break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try handling the SelectedCellsChanged event on your GridView with something like this:

```
private void gridView_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, GridViewSelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedCells != null && e.AddedCells.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (GridViewCellInfo cellInfo in e.AddedCells)
            {
                // do stuff
            }
        }
    }
```